# What are the morphisms in the 'category of CW-pairs'?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, category-theory, definition, cw-complexes

A *CW-pair* consists of a [CW complex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CW_complex) $X$ (with cell decomposition $\mathcal{E}\equiv\{e_\alpha\}_{\alpha\in I}$) together with one of its subcomplexes $A$ (a closed subspace of $X$ consisting of a union of cells in $\mathcal{E}$; this itself forms a CW complex).

In the definition of a *generalized cohomology theory* in the Wikipedia article [Cohomology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cohomology#Generalized_cohomology_theories), it mentions contravariant functors $h^i$ from the category of CW-pairs to the category of abelian groups. **But what are the morphisms in the category of CW-pairs?**

The Wiki on the [Cellular Approximation Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cellular_approximation_theorem#Cellular_approximation_for_pairs) says that a 'map' between CW pairs $(X,A)$ and $(Y,B)$ is a (presumably continuous) function $f:X\to Y$ with $f(A)\subseteq B$. But this does not seem like a strong enough condition to preserve the cell structure. For example, there is no mention that cells in $X$ are mapped into unique cells in $Y$, or even a finite or countable union of them. Please enlighten me and I apologise in advance for my naivety.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is the definition as you quoted: A map between CW pairs $(X,A)$ and $(Y,B)$ is a continuous map $f:X \to Y$ such that $f(A) \subseteq B$.

There is no need for $f$ to be cellular (i.e. preserve the skeletons). In fact, if you wish, you can make $f$ cellular up to homotopy anyhow - this is the statement of the Cellular Approximation Theorem.